# Does Mongoskin 2.1.0 support operations on MongoDB 3.x or 4.x?

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

When I updated my app's Node modules, MongoDB updated from 2.x to 3.x and I got a Dependency Error saying Mongoskin requires "mongodb":"^2.0". So I removed MongoDB 3.0 and installed 2.2.36, and all is fine.

Am I correct then to infer that Mongoskin, and its driver, will not cooperate and correctly operate against MongoDB 3.x or 4.x ? Or is it just that I cannot do the newer modern MongoDB 3.x/4.x operations but I can still do what I have been doing with Mongoskin to date?

Comment: their [driver compatibility page](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility) indicates driver 2.2 is only compatible to server 3.4 and before, but this only lists "recommended versions" so its unclear whether it works but not supported, partially works, or doesn't work at all

Comment: That driver compatibility page is for the MongoDB Native Node driver, I think. I don't see any mention of the Mongoskin driver there.

Comment: The response and views here are 2 years ago. through further experience, is there anything more known regarding compatibility and use of Mongoskin 2.1.0 with MongoDB 3.6.3 ?